# В каких случаях имеют смысл var-шаблоны?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

В C# 7.0 появились var-шаблоны которые судя по документации всегда `true`и нужны для создания новой переменной с таким же типом и значением.

Накидал тестовый метод, штука действительно работает.

```
private void TestPattern(object k)
{
    if (k is var test) Console.WriteLine("Result: " + test.GetType() + " " +  test);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Однако нахожу ее абсолютно бессмысленной. Более того, код как по мне жутко не читабельный и не очевидный.

Так для каких ситуаций собственно нужен этот шаблон?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это может быть применимо для введения временной переменной в выражении, [например](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/):

```
public void VarPattern(IEnumerable<string> s)
{
    if (s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is var v
        && int.TryParse(v, out var n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как чисто показательный пример конечно пойдет, но в целом по сути это только усложнение кода с объявлением локальной переменной. Как минимум визуально не очевидна область видимости этой переменной и условие усложнилось.  В отличие от нового крутого `out var n`!

Comment: @yolosora, в чем принципиальное отличие is var от out var?

Comment: Ну out var здесь безболезненно сокращает код. Меня всегда морозила необходимость объявлять заранее переменные для out-параметров

Comment: @yolosora, здесь на самом деле идет развитие этой темы, теперь не обязательно вообще заранее переменные объявлять

Comment: Это такая замена «оператору запятая» как бы.

Comment: @VladD, только в операторе запятая нельзя было объявлять переменные :)